# infinite loop UI

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm wondering if I can have an iOS program that stays in a loop, while the UI still works.

For example:

```
while (1) {
    //do some calc here
    Application.ProcessMessages();
}
```

Here the program stays in a loop, and uses Application.ProcessMesages() in order to update the screen, and get UI clicks, scrolls etc.

Is anything like this possible in IOS, maybe by using some form of a RunLoop?

I tried using a runLoop like this, it works for sometime, then the UI freezes eventually depending on what DoSomeWork(...) is doing for example downloading something from internet.

```
while(1) {
    DoSomeWork(....);
    CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, YES);
}
```

I know there are other ways of doing things, but I was wondering if anything like this can work in IOS?

Or Do you know what could cause the freeze?

Thanks

Comment: Before you find solutions, you should first ask whether this is actually necessary at all. Persistent polling is rarely needed in modern day programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI runs on the main thread, if you ahve an infinite loop doing work in the main thread it will block, you need to spawn a different thread in order to do the work, when you need to update the UI you should do so on the main thread as UIKit is not thread safe... here is one example of how to achive this, in my example the thread is being spawned to a selector (you can create subclasses of NSThread if you wish as well)

```
NSThread *sendThread=[[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(aSelector) object:nil];
[sendThread start];

-(void)aSelector
{
    //do some work
    //if you want to update the UI you should do so like so on the main thread
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //do stuff on main thread

    });
}
```

There is also the `NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread` that will also have the same effect, note that if  you call the dispatch main thread queue from the main thread it will block and lock.

Hoope this helps

Comment: why will the main loop block if its calling the RunLoop function, wouldn't the runLoop function process any events on the main loop, even though it's also on the main loop, apically recursively calling the main loop over again by calling RunLoop? wouldn't this create another thread to process any events on the main thread?

Comment: You are scheduling things on the main run loop correct? so depending on what they are doing (ie downloading something sync which  takes longer to do) they will block the main (UI) thread, why are you trying to do something like this anyway?

Comment: The only proper way to call the UI run loop is to return from your looping routine.

Answer (score 0):

The UI 'doesn't work'. You present a view and have one or more handlers set that act upon a button press or something else. You can start one or more other threads listening for other events like messages from network, location, battery low, you name it. There should be no need for a polling loop like in old days of CP/M.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't stay in an infinite loop on the main UI thread and not have the UI lock up or have the OS kill your app.  You either have to run the processing loop on another thread, or break the processing into chunks that only take a fraction of a second, and schedule these short operations with a queue or a timer.

Your background processing thread can send performSelecterOnMainThread to request updates to the screen.